# My app uses the old style YouTube player look and feel while sample app uses the new look and feel

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I looked over the code for the styling of the YouTube Player in the **Sample YouTube App** provided by Google (specifically for the Fragments); however, I don't see anything specific to styling of the video player.

I thought that was good, because the sample app uses the new look and feel of the video player, and it is the look I want.

However, when I run **My App**, the styling of the player is the old grey look and feel. I tried to update the styling to be the default, as the other styles would remove some of the chrome that I want. However, the style is still the old style.

I do the following, but this doesn't work...

`this.youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);`

**Both of these apps are running on the same physical phone, but I cannot seem to modify the look and feel of my app's YouTube player.**

### Code

```
public class YouTubeVideoFragment extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryFragment { // extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

    public static final String TAG = "video_fragment";
    private static final String ARG_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID = "video_id";

    private String mYouTubeVideoID;
    private YouTubeVideoFragmentListener mListener;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

    public YouTubeVideoFragment() { }

    public static YouTubeVideoFragment newInstance(@NonNull String youTubeVideoID) {

        YouTubeVideoFragment fragment = new YouTubeVideoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString(ARG_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID, youTubeVideoID);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {

        return (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

        this.youTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
        this.youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        playCurrentVideo();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mYouTubeVideoID = getArguments().getString(ARG_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
        }

        initialize(Developer.YOUTUBE_KEY, this);

    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of the SDK in your app?

[Here's the download link.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

Comment: I have **version 1.2.2**, both my app and the sample app use the same version. Confirmed by looking at the jar's MANIFEST.MF file

Comment: And your activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity?

Comment: I am using the Support Fragment version. My Fragment extends a Failure Recoverable Fragment (seen online) that extends `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`. I do the styling in the Fragment's `onInitializationSuccess(...)`

Comment: I got no other ideas then